# SQL error in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find the average number of transactions for every product key for the specified time keys. This is the query in DB2.

```
    select     
      act.product_key
      avg(act.cnt) as avg_transaction   
    from  tb1  as ca
    inner join  tb2  as act  
    on ca.base_key = act.base_key  and act.time = ca.time and act.product_key = ca.product_key
    group by act.product_key, act.time
    having act.time in (16476,16516, 16556,16596, 16636,16676,16716, 16756, 16796,16836,16876,16916,16956);
```

This is the error I am getting for the above query. I am not sure whats going wrong, this is the first time I am querying on DB2. Any suggestions would be great.

```
    Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=(;act.product_key
      avg;,, DRIVER=3.66.46
    SQLState:  42601
    ErrorCode: -104
    Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;(|act.product_key
      avg|,, DRIVER=3.66.46
    SQLState:  56098
    ErrorCode: -727
```

Comment: You're missing a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe what you want, you should move the `having` to a `where` clause and remove the time key from the `group by`:

```
select act.product_key, avg(act.cnt) as avg_transaction   
from  tb1 ca inner join
      tb2 act  
      on ca.base_key = act.base_key and act.time = ca.time and act.product_key = ca.product_key
where act.time in (16476, 16516, 16556,16596, 16636, 16676, 16716, 16756, 16796, 16836, 16876, 16916, 16956)
group by act.product_key;
```

I'm not sure if that will fix your problem.